# Dependency Injection on Authorization Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, authorization

I want to create a claim based authorization for my ASP.NET Core app:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Founders", policy =>
                          policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"));
    });
}
```

The problem is that I have a non trivial method to resolve the employee numbers (1 to 5) and I want to use a DI service:

```
public interface IEmployeeProvider {

  string[] GetAuthorizedEmployeeIds();
}
```

I would like to inject this service and use it in AddPolicy, something like:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Founders", policy =>
              policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber", *employeeProvider.GetAuthorizedEmployeeIds()));
});
```

**Note**

I know that I can write my own AuthorizationHandler where I can easily inject `IEmployeeProvider` but I'm against this pattern because:

1. There is a already a handler that does exactly what I need
2. I need to write a new handler for each claim type and each different requirement
3. This is an anti pattern because the employee ids should really be part of the requirement while the handler should be generic component that handles the requirements

So I'm looking for a way to inject services when the policy is being built

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to [Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) for the tip!

Since [AddAuthorization](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) is basically configuring `AuthorizationOptions` behind the scenes, I followed the same pattern only I used `OptionsBuilder` to configure options with dependencies

I created my own AddAuthorization method that accepts dependencies:

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddAuthorization<TDep>(
     this IServiceCollection services,
     Action<AuthorizationOptions, TDep> configure) where TDep : class
 {
     services.AddOptions<AuthorizationOptions>().Configure<TDep>(configure);
     return services.AddAuthorization();
 }
```

And now I can use it to properly configure the requirement:

```
services.AddAuthorization<IEmployeeProvider>((options, employeeProvider> =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Founders", policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber", employeeProvider.GetAuthorizedEmployeeIds())
    );
});
```

You can follow the same technique if you need more dependencies (`OptionsBuilder.Configure` supports up to 5 dependencies)

Obviously, this solution requires extra validation when upgrading to newer ASP versions, as the underlying implementation of `AddAuhtorization` may change

Comment: Glad to see you were able to work out a solution.  Check the suggested alternative I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124441/5233410). Happy Coding.

Comment: Looks like .NET 6 libraries don't support this.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs can you be specific, I didn't find anything not working or missing API in .NET 6

Comment: @MichaelShterenberg the `AddAuthorization` extension method no longer supports a lambda expression with respect to an `IServiceProvider` in .NET 6 EF.

Comment: Where do you see usage of `IServiceProvider` in the answer? The only use case is in the base form of `services.AddAuthorization()`

Answer (score 11):

To supplement the provided answer by [@MichaelShterenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12450145), the configuration delegate can use a `IServiceProvider` to allow for additional dependencies

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAuthorization(this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<AuthorizationOptions, IServiceProvider> configure) {
    services.AddOptions<AuthorizationOptions>().Configure<IServiceProvider>(configure);
    return services.AddAuthorization();
}
```

Which, based on the original example, can be used

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    service.AddScoped<IEmployeeProvider, EmployeeProvider>();

    services.AddAuthorization((options, sp) => {
        IEmployeeProvider employeeProvider = sp.GetRequiredService<IEmployeeProvider>();
        options.AddPolicy("Founders", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber", employeeProvider.GetAuthorizedEmployeeIds())
        );
    });

    //...
}
```

If there were other dependencies needed, they could be resolved from the service provider.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in this way, options above show me error about service root, but i try and finally make it

Program.cs

---

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{    
        new RegisterPoliciesService(builder.Services).Register(options);             
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionHandler>();
```

RegisterPolicies.cs

---

```
public class RegisterPoliciesService {
  private IServiceCollection _serviceProvider;
  public RegisterPoliciesService(IServiceCollection serviceProvider)
  {            
     _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;           
  }

  public void Register(AuthorizationOptions _autorizationOptions)
  {            
     using (var scope = _serviceProvider.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope())
     {
       var repositoryPermissions = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPermissionRepository>();                
        foreach (var permission in repositoryPermissions.GetChildPermissions())
        {
           _autorizationOptions.AddPolicy(permission.Rule!, policy => 
             policy.Requirements.Add(new PermissionRequirement(permission.Rule!)));
         }
      }
            
   }
}
```

Note

You must dispose createscope, this is why i use "using" clause to dispose createscope automatically whem the using finish.I do an automatic policies based on all data in permission table whose permission doesn't have a paprent permission, that means this permission contain the rule and it belongs to a parent permission to be able to group

Answer (score -1):

You can build a service provider using the BuildServiceProvider() method on the IServiceCollection:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IEmployeeProvider, EmployeeProvider>();

        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var employeeProvider = sp.GetService<IEmployeeProvider>();
        string[] values = employeeProvider.GetAuthorizedEmployeeIds();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {

            options.AddPolicy("Founders", policy =>
                      policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber", employeeProvider.GetAuthorizedEmployeeIds()));
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

interface and Class

```
public interface IEmployeeProvider
{
    string[] GetAuthorizedEmployeeIds();
}

public class EmployeeProvider : IEmployeeProvider
{
    public string[] GetAuthorizedEmployeeIds()
    {
        var data = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `IEmployeeProvider` may not be fully configured or not all DI services are configured at this time