# Getting Instance of AuthorizationHandler without ServiceProvider

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

In a dotnet core 3.1 Web API, I have defined an custom AuthorizationHandler.
The code to register the Handler in the `ConfigureServices` usually looks like this:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("ValidCustomer",
            policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ValidCustomerRequirement()));
    });
```

But my `ValidCustomerRequirement`-Handler uses constructor injection. Therefore dependency injection should create the instance. So I am using those lines for registration:

```
    services.AddScoped<ValidCustomerRequirement>();
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        options.AddPolicy("ValidCustomer",
            policy => policy.Requirements.Add(serviceProvider.GetService<ValidCustomerRequirement>()));
    });
```

Is there a better way without using the `BuildServiceProvider()`?

**Update**

following Nkosis suggestion, the code is elegant like this:

```
    services.AddScoped<ValidCustomerRequirement>();
    services.AddAuthorization((options, serviceProvider) =>
    {
        var validCustomerRequirement = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ValidCustomerRequirement>();
        options.AddPolicy("ValidCustomer", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(validCustomerRequirement));
    });
```

Though it throws an exception upon startup.
`Cannot resolve scoped service 'ValidCustomerRequirement' from root provider.`

When playing a bit, I found out the following:

```
    public interface ITestService
    {
        string GetAnswer();
    }
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public string GetAnswer() => "42";
    }
```

It works with a Singleton (as long as there is no scoped instance to create in the constructor parameters).

```
    services.AddSingleton<ITestService, TestService>();
    services.AddAuthorization((options, sp) =>
    {
        var testService = sp.GetService<ITestService>();
        Console.WriteLine(testService.GetAnswer());
    });
```

But it fails, when the `ITestService` is registered with `AddScoped`.

Interestingly it works, when the `ServiceProvider` is created with `BuildServiceProvider()`.

```
    services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();
    services.AddAuthorization((options, sp) =>
    {
        var testService = sp.GetService<ITestService>(); // fails

        var sp2 = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var testService2 = sp2.GetService<ITestService>(); // works
    });
```

When debugging I can see, that `sp` is of type
`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope`

while `sp2` is of type
`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider`

Comment: Have a look at the answer I gave here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124441/5233410

Comment: Thanks for the link, Nkosi!
Though still having an issue: `Cannot resolve 'ICustomersService' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'DbContext'`

Comment: Update the post with what you did and include the new issue.